# Proof by the Principle of Mathematical Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm trying to do my Maths assignment but I can't get this done. I'm a novice, so it's a bit hard to know which steps I need to follow in this one.

$$(1−x)(1+x+x^2+⋯+x^n)=1−x^{n+1}$$

My usual first step is to proof it when $n = 1$ and then when $n = k$. But the problem is that I don't know what $x$ is. I usually solve problems that only have $1$ variable.

Comment: You could use induction

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show us how you think you might get started. Presumably you have seen or written other inductive proofs. Try to use them as models. When you show us your attempt we may be able to help.

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides Since the title is “Proof by the Principle of Mathematical Induction”, I think that we can safely assume that the OP knows that.

Comment: Haha, omg. I didn't read the tittle at all. My bad

Comment: Can you show the equation holds for the case $n = 0$ or maybe for $n = 1$?  (You don't actually specify a bound on $n$, so it is unclear exactly which infinite set of statements you want to prove.)

Comment: Hint for the inductive step: $(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n+1}) = (1-x)(1+x+\dots+x^n) + (1-x)x^{n+1}$.

Comment: Hint: Let $S=(1+x+\dots+x^n)$. Then notice that $Sx=S+x^{n+1}-1$...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof by Induction: $\sum_0^nx^i=(1-x^{n+1})/(1-x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225698/proof-by-induction-sum-0nxi-1-xn1-1-x)

Comment: @CatherineSanchez $n$ is the only "variable". The identity you are trying to prove is supposed to be true for every value of $x$. Just do the algebra to check it  for yourself for $n=2$ and $n=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But the problem is I don't know what $x$ is." Well, I don't know what $x$ is either. But that's the point. It's an identity: it is true for all real values of $x$. And that's why it would have been better if the question was,

> Prove by induction, the following identity:
>
> $$(1−x)(1+x+x^2+⋯+x^n)\equiv1−x^{n+1}$$

Or, equivalently, the question could have been:

> Prove by induction, the following:
>
> $$(1−x)(1+x+x^2+⋯+x^n)=1−x^{n+1}\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\qquad \leftarrow\text{Statement P(n)}.$$

Now let's discuss what $P(n)$ is for different values of $n$.

Firstly, *beware*: $P(0)$ is **not** the statement $P(n)$ with $x$ replaced by $0$.

$P(0)$ is the statement $P(n)$ with $n$ replaced by $0$:

$$(1−x)(1)=1−x^{0+1}\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Is this statement true? Yes it is. This statement is $P(0).$ So $P(0)$ is true.

Ok, what is $P(1)$? It is:

$$(1−x)(1+x)=1−x^{1+1}\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Is this statement true? Yes it is. This statement is $P(1).$ So $P(1)$ is true.

Ok, now we've seen a little bit of what is going on, we need to get on and try to prove the inductive step.

So we assume $P(n)$ is true, that is, we assume:

$$(1−x)(1+x+x^2+⋯+x^n)=1−x^{n+1}\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\qquad \leftarrow\text{Statement P(n)}.$$

Now, we need to prove statement $P(n+1)$, that is, we need to prove:

$$(1−x)(1+x+x^2+⋯+x^n+x^{n+1})=1−x^{(n+1)+1}\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\qquad \leftarrow\text{Statement P(n+1)}.$$

We can, quite easily, prove statement $P(n+1)$ if we assume statement $P(n)$ is true. Can you finish this now?

Comment: I understand, thank you very much, I could already solve it!

Comment: You're most welcome!